# How do you actually get costumes in tiny tower?

Tags: tiny-tower

I want to buy a costume in tiny tower, but I can't find where to buy it from. Where can you buy costumes?

Answer (score 5):

Menu -> Bitizens -> [Insert Bitizen name here] -> Dress Up -> Costumes -> [Insert Costume here]

Once you buy the costume it is available to every other Bitizen in your tower.

Answer (score 1):

There is a button that says Menu on the bottom left of your screen. Then click on the **Bitizens** icon (which is the first one). Next, you pick any bitizen that is living in your tower and choose dress-up. A large green button with the word costumes should be there.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "buy" any costumes in Tiny Tower. You have to either randomly deliver a person wearing costume in the elevator, or the tasks the game gives you sometimes ask you to take people wearing a certain costume to a floor in the elevator